# What is cardinality of set of all intervals (a,b), where a, b are rational numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

We have set $S=\{ (a,b) | a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

And we know that $(a,b)\sim \mathbb{R}$ , so $k((a,b))=c$. And $\mathbb Q \sim \mathbb N$, so $k(\mathbb Q)=\aleph_0$.

I don't know how to put all informations together.

I was also thinking that $S \subset \mathbb R$ and than we know $k(S) \le k(\mathbb R)=c$.
But how to get other inclusion.

Comment: I think it is just countable since the set of all intervals $(a,b)$ with $a$, $b$ rational can be put into a bijection with $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ (with the small detail of having to worry about the fact that you need $a<b$ for the interval to make sense.)

Comment: What do you mean by $(a,b)\sim\mathbb{R}$? $S$ is countable.

Comment: But only a, b are from $Q$. In interval (a, b) are all real numbers.

Comment: Yes, but what are you counting if you are counting the number of elements of $S$? I'd say you're counting the amount of such intervals and not the elements in such an interval.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing the cardinality of the interval, with the cardinality of the *set* of intervals.

Note that while $\Bbb R$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, $\{\Bbb R\}$ has cardinality $1$. It is a singleton.

So to see that $\{(a,b)\subseteq\Bbb R\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$ is countable, note that each such interval is uniquely identified by its endpoints, which gives us a very natural injection (although not a bijection) into $\Bbb Q^2$.

Comment: Is there a reason for the downvote other than the user posting the answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** there exists an injective map $f: S \to \mathbb{Q}^2$. Since $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is countable, $S$ is at most countable.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with a simple example. The set of intervals $\{(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)\}$ contains only three intervals. You can easily define a bijection with the set of three integers: $\{0,1,2\}$, with cardinal $3$:
$$(0,1) \leftrightarrow 0$$
$$(1,2) \leftrightarrow 1$$
$$(2,3) \leftrightarrow 2$$
No matter if $(0,1)$ is an interval. Similarly, the set of segments  $\{(a,b)| a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ can be put in bijection with the set of ordered pairs  $\{[a,b]| a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, whose cardinality is $\mathbb{Q}^2$. Consider that the notation $[a,b]$ stands here for ordered pairs, since you have used $(a,b)$ for intervals